# Calling focus() on text input not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angularjs app I have a directive that makes a select-like area where I'm using ng-repeat to list "options" to select.

I'm trying to enable a submit on enter feature and have been doing that with `ng-click="focusInput(formName)"` where on the scope of the element I find this hidden text input I have (hidden with opacity: 0) and focus it so that when I press enter the form that the "select" box is in will save.

This method works everywhere else in the app but not here. For some reason `body` is getting focus whenever I try to focus the input either in console or through the `focusInput` function I have.

I've also tried using `$timeout` to no avail. This is no surprise though since I can't even focus the element in the console.

I'm not sure what's going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What dos your `focusInput()` function look like?

Comment: your situation is not clear enough. show us your code or better yet - create a jsfiddle

Comment: the `focusInput()` function is pretty simple:
    
    scope.focusInput(formName) {
      form = document.querySelector('form[name="' + formName + "]');
      input = form.querySelector('#hidden-input');
      input.focus();
    }

I've tried using $timeout and even scope.$apply to no avail. Since I can't get the element to focus even in the console, I'm thinking something else has got to be preventing it? I just don't know what nor the best way to find out.

Comment: So I figured out that on my macbook (chrome) the input that I am trying to focus on ng-click IS getting focus... but for some reason on my desktop (Ubuntu 14.04 Chrome) it's not? This is super bizarre... same code on both but different results?